# .NET to Java code transform

Tags: java, .net, code-conversion

I know about [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) that converts Java bytecode to .NET CIL. Is there a tool that performs reverse conversion? either with or without support for translating WinForms to JavaFX/Swing GUIs.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it actually translate? I thought it was just a JVM interpreter. Can you point to a reference?

Comment: My mistake, it's an intepreter..

Answer (score 4):

There is [GrassHopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130). 
Maybe you could use bridge instead ? My favorite one is [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) for obvious reasons. But try [this link list](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/links.shtml).

Comment: Just for the record.  Grasshopper is a commercial product.